# Creating a multi-paragraph Command Style for Lyx

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I have an existing LaTeX style which defines a `\solution` command (printing a box that also contains a solution as text, if `showSolution` is set).

I now created a LyX Style for this:

```
Style Solution
    Category Exam
    LatexName solution
    LatexType Command
End
```

The LaTeX code of the solution should look like `\solution{...}`, which works so far. But for complex solutions, I need the command to contain other paragraph types, such as Enumerations. Usually you can nest paragraphs in Lyx by changing the Environment type and press Tab (e.g. a `Verse` in an `Enumataion`), but this approach does not work for my `solution` command. How do I fix it?

Further Detaisl: I use Lyx to generate LaTeX code which I copy paste into a bigger project, so changing the LaTeX `solution` command is no option here. Lyx has to generate Code like:

```
\solution
{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Something
    \item On more thing
  \end{itemize}
}
```